# How do I get a job after a long gap since education being completed?

Tags: job-search

I've got a bachelor degree in Pharmacy followed by a master of technology degree in Biotechnology, which I did after securing a scholarship (completed in 2019). After that, I tried to secure a scholarship for a PhD but failed to do so for a number of reasons (in comments).

All in all, ever since qualifying the degree, I haven't done anything that I can possibly add to my resume as relevant experience. I've been trying to get a job for the past two years now. Most of my applications don't get a response. Some of them get a response and materialize into interviews (some of them went spectacular, IMO). After interviews, again, silence from recruiters, even after follow up mails. Some of them responded saying that I'm "overqualified" and hence they can't take me up for the job. Two such instances even happened when I reached out to friends for help in getting a job- being told that I'm "overqualified" *after* having gone through all interview rounds. That's true for jobs both in my core sector as well as places like customer representative jobs (I now really need a job so have been applying to any place that allows me to apply)

I hadn't done any internships before since my whole focus was to do a PhD, which would've been another step in fulfilling my dream to become a scientist.

Since it has been so long since I completed my education, I feel like my resume simply gets tossed in the bin wherever I now apply..

What does someone in my position do henceforth? I'm positive there are other people out there who have faced the same thing, albeit not too many. Where does one "start" something after such a long gap?

Comment: "failed to do so for a number of reasons (that I'd prefer not to put up)." Will you be willing to share these reasons in an interview?

Comment: Yes, @GregoryCurrie I have, too. I did try for the exam at the end of 2019, (since I'd failed to qualify by just two marks before). This time they gave the results as percentile, just (94.6 percentile was my score). My family is abusive. My farther isn't particularly educated and is a salesman (an industry unrelated to mine) but still tells me how to study (according to him, I'm not studying if I don't write 20 pages everyday, there's no studying without books and copies, I'm wasting time if I'm using a computer or my phone to study). These things spiralled me into depression.

Comment: Then COVID-19 followed where the industry expanded but jobs still shrank for freshers. I still tried to study but all my attempts to study were simply quashed by this "support" I got from my family. What do do say in interviews, however, is that I tried to secure a scholarship for PhD, and my best in the exam is currently 96.4 percentile. I work part time for a catering business that my aunt has set up, whenever she is in need of extra hands. That's practically what I've been doing. The interviews are spared from the depression and abusive family part, since the ones whom I did tell this

Comment: Didn't take it well, which I later on found out. People in my country don't really know what mental wellbeing is, at all, and they automatically consider anyone with mental issues automatically inept to do a job.

Comment: I suppose I should have been clearer that I wasn't asking, just wanted to know if you were, or were willing to share with employers.

Comment: I shared here anyway since I'm positive employers won't be able to trace my profile here and it'd likely help people reading the question to be able to gauge what they are about to answer to. Just to be clear, 94.6 percentile and 96.4 percentile are of two different attempts.

Comment: Did you apply for IT jobs such as software developers/programmers ? or biotech jobs ? or pharmacy jobs ?

Comment: "**M. Tech degree in Biotechnology**".  Is it a Master's degree ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 yes. It's a master degree. I've applied for biotech and pharmacy jobs, yes. A lot of them. IT jobs, not as much since I didn't have any subject that'd teach me even the basics of programming, but I did apply to them anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If many of your applications don't even get a response, and few secure an interview you should look for help writing these. There are many resources out there, look for them. Universities or community schools often provide courses. Maybe you have a friend with good writing skills, or someone who already wrote a lot of successful applications. ask them to review your communication and give feedback.

Second, if you have nothing to put on your resume for the last two years, you need to change that. Do volunteer work, start a project, do anything that helps to improve yourself. Fill your time with meaningful activities.

Of course that does nothing to explain what happened the last two years. You need an convincing answer to the question "Why is there a two year gap on your resume". Call it "personal orientation time" or whatever, just be able to justify it. How did you improve in the span of those years?

*edit*

In the comments you add that the gap was mostly caused by family problems and mental health. You are right, talking about depression in an interview is most probably a bad idea. I would rather go with unspecified "family issues". Not a good excuse, but better than disclosing a depression.

In another comment you add that you indeed did volunteer work. Add this on the resume! In your cover letter, talk about what you do there. Soft skills and being a "likeable" person who works toward a better society is often a lot more important to a company than a degree.

Comment: I did attempt exams to secure a scholarship. I have been doing volunteer work with organisations (NGOs that work with providing education and medical help to the less fortunate) as well. I meant to say that I haven't done anything relevant that I can add to my resume in terms of the courses I've studied. Job applications in my country seldom have anything added to them apart from one's CV and the details that are there in the CV to be typed out.

Comment: @Timon thanks for the clarification. All the infos from your comments should be in your question. If you did work for NGOs, this is certainly something to put on a resume. You have your degrees, so it's clear that you know your field of study. What the volunteer work shows is that you also care for those around you, and you have a work ethic. Thats worth a lot. "Soft Skills" are more important than many graduates think.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will add these to my resume as well. I've been discouraged to add them before since it's "just volunteer work" and it's generally looked down upon, at least that's what I've been told by multiple people around. That it's perceived as a "filler" in a resume and that my resume is better left without it.. Because of the fact that it's not relevant to what I've actually studied. Its confusing, really.

Comment: @Timon well yes, they are a filler. Of course "real" work in your field would be better, but if you don't have anything else to add, why omit it? Showing a gap without anything is the worst case. The HR representative will assume you sat around watching TV.

Comment: Alison Green at [Ask a Manager](https://askamanager.org) recommends using something like, "I had some family issues which are resolved now." Or use health or both but make it clear that they're no longer a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are being rejected with the feedback that you are "overqualified", then you are applying for the wrong jobs.

It's also possible that you are talking too much about getting a PhD and/or being a scientist and that is making potential employers feel that you won't stick around.

If you really want a job that doesn't match your background, you can leave parts of your education off of your resume.